# Extract a particular key values to separate array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

The array structure is like this

```
    $array1 = [
   "101" => [
        "name" => "Robin",
        "age" => "25"
    ],
    "102" => [
        "name" => "asRobin",
        "age" => "25"
    ],
    "103" => [
        "name" => "Roasbin",
        "age" => "25"
    ],
    "104" => [
        "name" => "Robiasn",
        "age" => "25"
    ]
  ]
```

Here I got the ids in a particular array using `$ids = array_keys($array1)` function. Now likewise how can i extract the names

Comment: What do you want to do with them when you have them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [array_map](http://php.net/manual/function.array-map.php) :

```
$names = array_map(function($a) { return $a["name"]; }, $array1);
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : 
I just remembered that function, which gives a more elegant way to do that :

```
$names = array_column($array1);
```